# What cloud platform supports playframework?

Tags: playframework, cloud-hosting, playframework-2.0

I know 2 now:

1. http://heroku.com: Supports play1 and play2, has free plan.
2. http://www.playapps.net: Supports play1, unknown play2, no free plan.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There many options for deploying play framework applications on the cloud

Like codemwnci said, most of them work with a war deployment.

- Heroku for play!

  princing: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/29/play/
  (seems like you get 1 web dyno + 5mb postresql db for free)

  sample: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play

  db: postgresql

  deployment: native via git

  tutorial: https://github.com/opensas/play-demo/wiki/Step-13---deploy-to-heroku

  play2 support: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ProductionHeroku
- Openshift

  A PaaS offering by Red Hat

  module: http://www.playframework.org/modules/openshift

  pricing: you get 5 apps, with 500MB space each, for free, supports mysql, mongo, jenkins, perl, php, python and java

  article: http://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/play-framework-on-the-cloud-made-easy-openshift-module/

  db: mysql, mongodb, postgresql

  deployment: war deploy via git (or using the module)

  (Using the raw cartridge is possible to deploy play apps natively, I'll see if I can write a tutorial on the next few days...)

  vote for native support: https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/content/native-support-for-play-framework-application

  tutorial: https://github.com/opensas/play-demo/wiki/Step-12.5---deploy-to-openshift
- Google Application Engine

  module: http://www.playframework.org/modules/gae-1.4/home

  cons: can't use mysql, should not use JPA

  http://www.playframework.org/modules/siena-2.0.0/home

  db: uses it's own datastore (Instead of JPA it is advised to use siena)

  deployment: via module

  nice example: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2011/01/first-play-framework-gae-siena-application-tutorial-example.html

  tutorial: https://github.com/opensas/play-demo/wiki/Step-14---deploy-to-gae
- dotCloud

  module: http://www.playframework.org/modules/cloudbees

  princing: https://www.dotcloud.com/pricing/
  (there's a free plan with 10MB db)

  floss: https://www.dotcloud.com/pricing/pricing-faq/
- AWS - Amazon Web Services

  pricing: http://aws.amazon.com/en/ec2/#pricing

  pricing: http://aws.amazon.com/en/elasticbeanstalk/#pricing

  samples:
  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javadev2-19/index.html
  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javadev2-16/index.html
- Jelastic -

  homepage: http://jelastic.com/

  module: http://www.playframework.org/modules/jelastic
- CleverCloud

  homepage: https://www.clever-cloud.com/en/

  pricing: https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/clever-cloud-overview/pricing/

  deploying for Scala: https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/scala/play-framework-2/
  deploying for Java (same?): https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/java/play-framework-2/

There are lots of options, and new ones come out every day...

Here's an article with a list of the Public and Private Cloud PaaS for java: http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/regarding-java-platforms

Regarding play 2 support, heroku provides native support and once war deployment is ready (is scheduled for next minor release) you'll be able to deploy to most of them. I managed to deploy a play2 app to openshift using the do-it-yourself cartridge, here's a [screencast](http://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/deploying-play-framework-2-apps-with-java-and-scala-to-openshift/) and a [tutorial](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/supporting-play-framework-on-openshift-with-the-diy-application-type))

Comment: Let me just add, the PlayApps solution is not a cloud based one. You cannot scale up/down your server on the fly.

Comment: An awesome one is missing: [Clever Cloud](http://www.clever-cloud.com/en/), a PaaS which auto-scales (vertical / horizontal). It supports Play 1 and 2 (Java and Scala flavours). (no free plan but you can try it for free)

Comment: Just an update: CloudBees is shutting down its cloud hosting service

Answer (score 4):

At the present date, Heroku and Playapps are your options for native Play support. There is a new one being developed that will also support web sockets (called [Incipit](https://incipit.ws/)), currently in beta supports 2.0 natively through uploading a zip file from the dist commmand and 1.0 through exporting as a WAR and uploading.

Your other option is to use one of the many cloud platforms, but exporting your application as a WAR file. Not ideal, but it opens up options for the likes of CloudBees and OpenShift and many more. There is also an open community request to add Play support to OpenShift [here](https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/content/native-support-for-play-framework-application).

Answer (score 4):

Cloud Foundry now has support for play 2.0 as well. Haven't tried it though.
See: http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2012/05/31/cloud-foundry-now-supports-play/.
By the way, Playapps stopped its services. It promotes Heroku on their website.

Answer (score 2):

I am using [DotCloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/), which offers a free plan
So far it looks good !

There is [a module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/dotcloud) to make deployment easier for this platform.